# Display all subtotals and a single total for every bill

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a query with this result:

```
billno painter_id painter_rate painter_subtotal sum_1
2      2          5            30               30
7      2          20           160              255
7      2          20           80               255
7      2          5            15               255
```

Using the following SQL:

```
SELECT a1.billno, a1.painter_id, a1.painter_rate, 
    a1.painter_subtotal, a2.painter_subtotal AS sum_1 
FROM voucher_paint_detail AS a1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT billno,sum(painter_subtotal) AS painter_subtotal 
    FROM voucher_paint_detail where painter_id='BMLWA' GROUP BY billno) AS a2
ON a2.billno = a1.billno
WHERE a1.painter_id = '2'
```

on this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [voucher_paint_detail] (
    [srno] INTEGER NULL,
    [painter_id] TEXT NULL,
    [painter_rate] REAL NULL,
    [paint_quantity] INTEGER NULL,
    [painter_subtotal] REAL NULL,
    [transaction_id] INTEGER NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([srno])
)
```

i want the the data to look like

```
billno painter_id painter_rate painter_subtotal sum_1
2      2          5            30               30
7      2          20           160   
7      2          20           80    
7      2          5            15               255
```

Comment: -1 because you have not provided the table structure, you have not asked a question in any way, you have merely expressed the need to have a different output and because you have not shown any try at the problem you want to solve.

Comment: I m NEWBIE dont know  how this works sorry  about that

Comment: CREATE TABLE [voucher_paint_detail] (
[srno] INTEGER  NULL,
[painter_id] TEXT  NULL,
[painter_rate] REAL  NULL,
[paint_quantity] INTEGER  NULL,
[painter_subtotal] REAL  NULL,
[transaction_id] INTEGER  NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ([srno])
)

Comment: I have told you what is missing in your question. I am not downvoting because you did not know how to format your question. I am downvoting because you did not even ask a question.

Comment: SORRY about that . i tried to edit my post but was not posting due to some formatting issues in the post

Answer (score 0):

Your JOIN is rather verbose, so let's rewrite your query with a correlated subquery in the SELECT clause (the meaning is the same, but this allows us to avoid computing the sum for uninteresting records):

```
SELECT billno,
       painter_id,
       painter_rate,
       painter_subtotal,
       (SELECT SUM(painter_subtotal)
        FROM voucher_paint_detail
        WHERE billno     = a1.billno
          AND painter_id = a1.painter_id
       ) AS sum_1
FROM voucher_paint_detail AS a1
WHERE painter_id = 'BMLWA'
```

To be able to differentiate the last record of a bill from the other records, we have to impose some ordering on all the records of one bill.
Here, I use `srno`:

```
SELECT billno,
       painter_id,
       painter_rate,
       painter_subtotal,
       (SELECT SUM(painter_subtotal)
        FROM voucher_paint_detail
        WHERE billno     = a1.billno
          AND painter_id = a1.painter_id
       ) AS sum_1
FROM voucher_paint_detail AS a1
WHERE painter_id = 'BMLWA'
ORDER BY billno,
         srno
```

Then the last record of a bill is a record for which no other record exists that has the same bill number but a higher `srno`:

```
SELECT billno,
       painter_id,
       painter_rate,
       painter_subtotal,
       CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT srno
                             FROM voucher_paint_detail
                             WHERE billno     = a1.billno
                               AND painter_id = a1.painter_id
                               AND srno       > a1.srno)
            THEN (SELECT SUM(painter_subtotal)
                  FROM voucher_paint_detail
                  WHERE billno     = a1.billno
                    AND painter_id = a1.painter_id)
            ELSE NULL
       END AS sum_1
FROM voucher_paint_detail AS a1
WHERE painter_id = 'BMLWA'
ORDER BY billno,
         srno
```

Note: the EXISTS subquery is not likely to be much more performant than the SUM subquery, so you're unlikely to save anything.